# Хитрая задачка по блоку try catch finally

Tags: java

```
public class ReturnFromFinally {

    public static int Test() {
        try {
            return 2;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Test());
    }
}
```

Выводит 3, а не 2.

Возможно это как-то связано с записью информации в стек.

В чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: `finally` вызывается практически всегда, отсюда и 3, детали см. в этом [ответе](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/121979/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-finally-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-try-return

Answer (score 3):

Ошибки нет, это поведение by design, насколько я представляю.

Вот не понимаю, зачем вообще помещать return в finally. Кстати, в C# return из finally запрещён.

Answer (score 2):

В конструкции try...catch...finally блок finally всегда подлежит исполнению и исполняется после блоков try и catch. "return 2;" - записывает 2 как возвращаемое методом значение, но исполнение метода не может быть завершено до исполнения блока finally. "return 3;" - перезаписывает возвращаемое значение, после чего исполнение метода завершается.