# Как в IntelliJ IDEA открыть декомпилированный байт-код?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, байткод

Оказывается, [можно сделать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729377/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-finally-%D0%B2-java#729388) такую удивительную магию как:

1. Написать программу.
2. Скомпилировать в байт-код.
3. Снова открыть её в IntelliJ IDEA.
4. Исходный код, сгенерированный из байт-кода, может оказаться другим!

**Вопросы:**

1. Как это сделать (инструкцию бы, с краткими пояснениями).
2. Если я напишу программу, потом скомпилю в байт-код, потом открою через IntelliJ IDEA, потом снова скомпилю, может ли поведение программы во второй сборке отличаться от поведения в первой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Набираете код класса в IDEA.
2. Собираете проект <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>.
3. Находите .class файл в дереве проекта (Папка `out` для обычного java-проекта, `target` -  для maven-проекта).
4. Открываете двойным кликом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы красавчик. У меня получилось!

Comment: ну как человек разбирающийся, ответьте на вторую половину вопроса, хотя бы как имхо: Может ли измениться поведение программы после переоткрытия из байткода? Да или НЕТ?

Answer (score 2):

Intellij IDEA это просто как пример, можно воспользоваться Eclipse, он тоже так умеет.

Вообще компиляция происходит вызовом компилятора `javac` он находится в папке `jdk\bin`, вызываете с путём к файлу исходного кода, например `C:\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javac.exe Main.java`, если у вас `Window`, `jdk` при этом находится там, куда вы его установили и может иметь другую версию. Рядом с файлом Main.java появится файл Main.class, который можно открыть как файл в `IDEA`

Но вообще, чтобы просто посмотреть исходный байт код, достаточно создать `Java` проект в `IDEA`, скомпилировать и открыть папку куда скомпилировался файл

[image: Расположение файла]

Comment: извиняйте, не понятно. Можете переписать так:
1. Набираю код в Intellij Idea. Сохраняю проект.
2. Открываю командную строку. Набираю команды ...
3. Файл сохранился в директории ...
4. Открываю это из директории С:\ ...
5. Смотрю, код изменился. PROFIT!

Comment: вам тоже большое спасибо, просто коллега этот вопрос объяснил чуть-чуть более понятно.